# WCF - how to connect to specific instance

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Using WCF, .NET 4.5, Visual Studio 2015, and want to use per-session instancing, not singleton. The services provided are to be full-duplex, over tcp.net.

Suppose I have two machines, A & B...

B as a client, connects to a "service" provided as a WCF service on same machine B, and starts talking to it, call it object “X”. It ALSO connects to another instance of the same service, call it object “Y”

A as a client, wants to connect to, and use, exact same objects B is talking to, objects “X” and “Y”, except now it’s remote-remote, not local-remote.

“X”  and “Y” are actually a video servers, and both have “state”.

Can I do this? How, when I’m a client, do I specify WHICH service instance I want to connect to?

Obviously, on machine "B", I could kludge this by having the services just be front-ends with no "state", which communicate with some processes running on "B", but that would require I write a bunch of interprocess code, which I hate.

Machine B is expected to be running 100's of these "video server" instances, each one being talked to by a local master (singleton) service, AND being talked to by end-user machines.

I realize this question is a bit generic, but it also addresses a question I could not find asked, or answered, on the Internets.

I just thought of one possible, but kludge-y solution: since the master service is a singleton, when service instance "X" is created by the end-user, it could connect to the singleton master service, through a proxy to the singleton. Then, the singleton can talk *back* to instance "X" over a callback channel. Yeah, that would work! messy, but possible.

I'd still like to know if end user A and end user B can both talk to the same (non-singleton) service instance on machine C through some funky channel manipulation or something. As I understand the rules of WCF, this simply isn't possible. Perhaps *maybe* if you're hosting the service yourself, instead of IIS, but even then, I don't think it's possible?

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same problem and solved it by creating two service references, one for the local one for the remote. Let's call it `LocalServiceClient` and `RemoteServiceClient`.

In a class, create a property called `Client` (or whatever you like to call it):

```
public LocalServiceClient Client {
     get {
          return new LocalServiceClient();
     }
}
```

Okay this is for only one of them. Just create another now, and set which one to use with a compiler flag:

```
#if DEBUG
public LocalServiceClient Client {
     get {
          return new LocalServiceClient();
     }
}
#else

public RemoteServiceClient Client {
     get {
          return new RemoteServiceClient();
     }
}
#endif
```

Instantiate any instances of your `Client` using `var` keyword, so it will be implicitly-typed, or just use `Client` directly:

```
var client = Client;
client.DoSomething...
//or
Client.DoSomething...
```

This way, when you are working locally, it will connect to the local service, and on release configuration (make sure you are on `Release` when publishing) it will compile for the remote one. Make sure you have the exact same signature/code for both services though at the WCF-side.

There are also methods that you can dynamically do it in code, or like in `web.config`, they would also work for sure, but they are usually an overkill. You probably need to connect to local one in debugging, and the remote one in production, and this is going to give you exactly what you need.